# DISTINCT into SQL statement is not working very well

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

The below code is working fine with one problem that is shown many records where it suppose to show only one. (for example: if a user from **UserInfo** table has 10 ads into **ads** table where 5 of those ads has value similar to Query String **result** value, so he repeat the user 5 times where it suppose to appear once whatever he have ads where **Wtag** column.)

```
  if (Request.QueryString["Searchfor"] != null)
                        {

                            using (SqlConnection srcbizhsql = new SqlConnection(sc))
                            {

                                srcbizhsql.Open();
                                SqlDataAdapter DAsearchbiz = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT DISTINCT UI.[UID],UI.[Country],UI.[State],UI.[City],UI.[Logo],UI.[Website],UI.[UsrType],UI.[BizCateg],UI.[BizSubCateg],UI.[Twitter],UI.[GooglePlus],UI.[Facebook],UI.[CompNme],UI.[RegDate] ,SUBSTRING([CompDesc],1,40) AS CompDesc  ,AD.[Wtags] FROM UserInfo AS UI , ads AS AD WHERE UI.UID = AD.UID and UI.[Country]= @Location AND UI.[UsrType]= 'Business' AND CHARINDEX(@Wtag, AD.[Wtags] )>0 ORDER BY UI.[RegDate] DESC", sc);

                                DataSet DSsrchBiz = new DataSet();

                                DAsearchbiz.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", cookie.Value);
                                DAsearchbiz.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wtag", result);

                                DAsearchbiz.Fill(DSsrchBiz);
                                SrchbizHomLstviw.DataSource = DSsrchBiz.Tables[0];
                                SrchbizHomLstviw.DataBind();
                                SrchMultiView.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
                                RebindAds();
                                RebindJobs();

                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Copy your query into SSMS and check manually what is different ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound i tried before but it is difficult to do it in SSMS as the query string suppose to be exist

Comment: FOr me I think this is SUBSTRING([CompDesc],1,40) or  AD.[Wtags] that cause your issue

Comment: Your indents are not working very well either.

Answer (score 0):

You really should start using ANSI-92 style joins instead of the older ANSI-89 style. The syntax has been around over 20 years now. [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Here is your query with "modern" joins and some formatting.

```
SELECT DISTINCT UI.[UID]
    , UI.[Country]
    , UI.[State]
    , UI.[City]
    , UI.[Logo]
    , UI.[Website]
    , UI.[UsrType]
    , UI.[BizCateg]
    , UI.[BizSubCateg]
    , UI.[Twitter]
    , UI.[GooglePlus]
    , UI.[Facebook]
    , UI.[CompNme]
    , UI.[RegDate] 
    , SUBSTRING([CompDesc], 1, 40) AS CompDesc  
    , AD.[Wtags] 
FROM UserInfo AS UI
JOIN ads AS AD ON UI.UID = AD.UID 
WHERE UI.[Country] = @Location 
    AND UI.[UsrType] = 'Business' 
    AND CHARINDEX(@Wtag, AD.[Wtags])> 0 
ORDER BY UI.[RegDate] DESC
```

What I don't understand however is what the problem is.

Comment: the problem is there is two table UserInfo and ads, so the website visitor will write a word into search textbox so this word is (result query string) so UserInfo table has many users info and those users adding their ads into ads table. so when website visitor search for Toyota the it suppose to show users info whose had ads contain Toyota into Wtag column in ads table. so the problem IS for example if Sean Lange has 40 ads into ads table 30 of them has Toyota value into Wtag then it will show 30 where it suppose to show only one record

Comment: Then either remove AD.Wtags from the query or use top 1 (if you use top 1 you should also include an order by).

Comment: No way to remove AD.Wtags this is the main part of the code, i havent tried top 1 but i don't think it's going to work .

Comment: Well unless you can provide some details like the table definitions and sample data to reproduce the issue this is nearly impossible to help. You have a distinct on your query. Which column(s) are NOT distinct? It has to be Wtags, or maybe CompDesc since we don't which table that comes from. Help to help you by giving me some info.

Comment: I dont know if thats will make it more clear, but i make quick screen record explaining the issue hope that will be more clear to understand the issue, please have a look https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh2GY2_whVM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: No I am not going to start watching videos about your issue. If you really want some help you need to post details, not videos. Try this link. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: ok as you like i tried to explain the issue by writing as much as i can and also i make a video to make more clear, thats what i can do if i can explain more i will do it from the beginning but that is my max

Comment: Apparently you didn't read the article I suggested. It states you should post tables and data. That makes it so others can actually run queries and help you solve the problem. I don't want to watch a video of your program, I want to help you with your sql.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all it has been fixed after many tried as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT UI.[UID] ,UI.[Country] ,UI.[State] ,UI.[City] ,UI.[Logo] ,UI.[Website] ,UI.[UsrType] ,SUBSTRING(UI.[CompDesc], 1, 60) AS CompDesc ,UI.[BizCateg] ,UI.[BizSubCateg] ,UI.[Twitter] ,UI.[GooglePlus] ,UI.[Facebook] ,UI.[CompNme] ,UI.[RegDate] FROM UserInfo AS UI JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ads.[UID] FROM ads WHERE CHARINDEX(@Wtag, ads.[Wtags])> 0) AS AD ON AD.[UID] = UI.[UID] WHERE UI.[Country] = @Location AND UI.[UsrType] = 'Business' ORDER BY UI.[RegDate] DESC
```